# How do I change this Gstreamer pipeline for the MP4 to play on Firefox?

Tags: gstreamer, mp4

How do I change this pipeline so that I can play my mp4 videos from a browser?

```
        gst-launch-1.0 -e \
                rtspsrc location="rtsp://username:password@${CAMERA}:554/" ! \
                rtph265depay ! \
                h265parse ! \
                mp4mux ! \
                filesink location=$FILENAME 2>&1 > gst.${CAMERA}.log &
```

I can playback with ffplay and gst-play, but no browsers work, nor does the mac viewer.

```
% ffmpeg -i 20230128204859.mp4

ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20230128204859.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomiso2
    creation_time   : 2023-01-29T04:48:59.000000Z
  Duration: 00:59:59.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2109 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 5661:5680 DAR 629:355], 2104 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 3k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-01-29T04:48:59.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: many browsers don't yet support h265, you'll need to convert to h264 or vp8 or similar.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Ah, that was it, Just needed to transcode. Didn't occur to me that 265 isn't supported yet, its so old I thought it was. Thanks! This link helped. https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg252-vcu/Transcode-from-H.265-to-H.264